# 2.8 Materials sometimes not applied

Tags: texturing, materials

I've just moved to 2.8. Opened my Rover model and I am noticing that for some reason the material is not showing up right on some objects, while showing fine on others. This is the same material used on all of them. They are all UV unwrapped. It's working fine in 2.79. I tried re-unwrapping them, but it doesn't do anything. Is there something specific to the beta that would cause this?

Here is the blend
https://www.dropbox.com/s/s0hk4r48l2ahtag/packedrover.blend?dl=0

See pic for example

[image]

Comment: Are these materials from 2.7 ? it won't work with Eevie.
The models that render correctly come from 2.7 also ?
I will check out the blend file when I can access my pc and if you are not answered yet.

Comment: This is a Cycles view, not Eevie. Even if that were the case, that would not explain some working and some not, they would all not work I would think. Also have seen in 2.8 videos that materials should work just fine...

Comment: until now it's a beta and you don't want to import blend from 2.7 to 2.8 it is specified that it will cause troubles

Comment: @Yvain As far as I heard Blender is particularly good at backwards compatability, where is that specified?

Comment: Yes It does, I think! @WhatAMesh

Comment: @MajorTom There's nothing wrong with materials, I mean they are applied successfully see [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h2vwo8EezQiUHefxdSEMuMEi8JdkYOya/view?usp=sharing). I think problem is with your lighting.

Comment: And also note that all of your image textures are not packed and because of that we can't access your image textures, see how to do  [Exporting blender file with textures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604436/exporting-blender-file-with-textures)

Comment: This is not a lighting issue. It is clear in the picture I posted the "roughness" of the plastic on items like the tire tread and spherical canopy. But the the front piece and some of the attached items have the same color but not the texture. 

All objects were made the same way. It doesn't follow that if the issue is moving to 2.8 that only SOME of those don't work.  

It's very clear on this render (https://www.dropbox.com/s/103vs37bl5igq7b/render5.jpg?dl=0) that the cover has the texture, but the base of it does not - but they are almost an identical item using the same material.

Comment: I repacked the blend, hopefully everything is there if you want to look again. - https://www.dropbox.com/s/q2dfxn33oynz16a/texturing3.blend?dl=0